# Teams Bot on Action "Unable to reach app..." then 1 seconds later "Your response was..." issue

Tags: bots, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have developed a Microsoft Teams App Bot. Im running it in Firebase as a function.
This is the function:

```js
exports.teamsBot = functions
    .region("europe-west1")
    .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
        await adapter.process(req, res,
            (context) => bot.run(context)
        );
    });
```

adapter is a CloudAdapter.

I have a card with 3 actions:

```js
{
                "type": "ActionSet",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "title": "",
                        "data": {
                            "action": "feedback-up",
                            "feedbackId": feedback.id
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "title": "",
                        "data": {
                            "action": "feedback-down",
                            "feedbackId": feedback.id
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "title": " Did not attend",
                        "data": {
                            "action": "feedback-no-show",
                            "feedbackId": feedback.id
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

I retrieve the result in onMessage in my bot. I do some magic and store the values and reply with:

```js
 await context.sendActivity("Thanks for your valuable feedback... ");
```

The process works however I get a strange annoying issue.
First when I click the button I direct get: "Unable to reach app. Please try again." and then like 1 second later when my reply hits it changes to I guess the correct one "Your response was sent to the app".

So from a user perspective it looks like something is first wrong then its correct. It feels like the Action is waiting for some sort of first reply that Im missing. Then when my reply comes it feels like ouuu its okay now.

Anybody has any Idea on this?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! Can you make sure Teams channel is added on Azure portal for your bots? If not, pls add it and let us know if the issue still repros.

Comment: Hey, yes its added. I guess it would not work at all if it wasn't? But its added.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I have faced similar kinds of issues in prod or uat apps. If the response takes to much time probably 4 or 5 , etc seconds then this particular message appears under the adaptive card. You can verify on your end.

Comment: Yes, it happens in the case where the response takes more than nearly 2-3 sec and there doesn't seem to be any specific solution available for this